# TypeScript: Create type that removes properties of an interface/class based on their value-types

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types, conditional-types

Imagine the class:

```js
class Person {
  name = "Ann";
  sleep() { /*...*/ }
  eat() { /*...*/ }
}
```

Now I would like to create a type that extracts only the methods:

```js
// should work:
const personMethods: MethodsOf<Person> = { sleep() {}, eat() {} };
const names: keyof MethodsOf<Person>[] = ['sleep', 'eat'];
// should fail:
const personMethods: MethodsOf<Person> = { notAPersonMethod() {} };
const names: keyof MethodsOf<Person>[] = ['not', 'existing', 'methods'];
```

I could not find anything in the typescript docs, and my attempts failed so far. I tried:

```
type MethodKeys<
  Type extends object,
  Key extends keyof Type,
> = keyof Record<Type[Key] extends AnyFn ? Key : never, any>;

type Methods<Type extends object> = {
  [Property in MethodKeys<Type, keyof Type>]: Type[Property];
};

const test: MethodKeys<Person> = 'name'; // works, but shouldn't :(
const test2: Partial<Methods<Person>> = { name: 'Ann' }, // works too :/
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you meant `Array<keyof MethodsOf<Person>>` or `(keyof MethodsOf<Person>)[]` there. Note the precedence, `keyof MethodsOf<Person>[]` applies `keyof` on the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a type that gives you back the method names given the class/interface. You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to create an object type where each value represents each method names. Then, you can index that object type to get its value type - which will yield a union of all method names.

```
type MethodKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...x: any) => any ? K : never;
}[keyof T]
```

Now, you can use [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to pick those method keys from your class/interface.

```
type MethodsOf<T> = Pick<T, MethodKeys<T>>;
```

And your given testcases work correctly-

```
// works
const personMethods: MethodsOf<Person> = { sleep() {}, eat() {} };
const names: Array<keyof MethodsOf<Person>> = ['sleep', 'eat'];

const personMethods1: MethodsOf<Person> = { notAPersonMethod() {} };
// ^ Type '{ notAPersonMethod(): void; }' is not assignable to type 'MethodsOf<Person>'.
const names1: Array<keyof MethodsOf<Person>> = ['not', 'existing', 'methods'];
// ^ Type '"not"' is not assignable to type 'MethodKeys<Person>'.
// ...and more
```

Check it out on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gWAFDWjTAFt5oBeaAIgEE00qBuPAiEeeABwAoBKLaAHoAVADpxwwdAC+LaPDAAXPgJHjRkmXlm48igJ6cyAWXiKAFigAmAaXj6IAHgAqAPgpY5BANo3oASwwAa3sUADNoZwBdAC5I3yj5AA9FeDQrGG51JLiwNH1+cnc8-WgAfmg-OLR4ADckZlxpbxD9cMiovD1DEzNLDIB5MJd3Slh-YCCXABpoUwtrOwcR10a8QSkISwBXECtoAHcURCCYvGB0CEVoI2R0ef6IOIfrCCHHBDu0UYE2Dh5+JhpLMFMpAdIZI0LmgroQSPAntAaIhEGB9I5Wu0XoNhp9UN8ft4AOR-LhE2ZE0FEqJrXAbaBbFC7fZhMD+EBnXDQ2G3fHYiAARmefVe7zx6B+mEIKEUNHFaGxKiBkPOl2uRFIgriyNR6MxEX5YqQ+NchKJaBl5OglKS-iugQA5laiaQFhlqY0gA).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Chase's solution, you could use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in order to filter out the keys that have a function value:

```js
type MethodHelper<T, K extends keyof T> = K extends any
    ? T[K] extends Function ? K
    : never : never;
```

Then use that to implement `MethodKeys` and `Methods`:

```js
type MethodKeys<T> = MethodHelper<T, keyof T>;
type Methods<T> = {
    [K in MethodKeys<T>]: T[K]
};


const test: MethodKeys<Person> = 'name'; // doesn't work
const test2: MethodKeys<Person> = 'sleep'; // does work
const test3: Partial<Methods<Person>> = { name: 'Ann' }; // doesn't work
const test4: Partial<Methods<Person>> = { sleep() {} }; // does work
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGtNYAtvNALzQBEAgmmhQNy7QQjzwAOAFAJRbQD0AKgB0owf2gBfJvDAAXHnyGjh4qdmnY5AT3YkAsvDkALFABMAEvBB7EAHgAqAGmgBpaPAAec+GjMwAa3htFAAzaAcAPjI3D29ff2gwNG1oAH4IgG1XAF04nz8YADEAVzRgOQBLdHTYgC58eAA3JGgGtGakRi1dAyNTM1dgiEdo8kMTcysbJEcXIJDwqMYdPWgJgZGomJw8PGzoSowN8yHtLcichodsnI1u7GB0CDloHxeGk8HhuwRkdDG0AA5ARiED6AIJGYUPAIGgga8AO4oRABR7PV7vOQAJk+-VOPz+qDQgKBLDY7HBkOg0Nh0GRqPRaBeb1hcgAzA1YGBEFUwCA7F8RkSAYDMPgiPAGkCaPCpBD+FCYXCEfSUWinszMWyACxcnl8gVC35IYmRMXMVgcRSYSTy6m0mAMtFAA)